# Symmetric Polynomial in roots is in $F[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials

I recently came across the following claim.

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $f\in F[X]$ have roots $y_1, \ldots , y_d$ in the algebraic closure of $F$. Define

$$ g_h = \prod_{1\le \lambda < \mu \le d} (X - y_\lambda - y_\mu -h y_\lambda y_\mu)$$

where $h \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The claim is that since $g_h$ is symmetric in $y_1, \ldots , y_d$, $g_h \in F[X]$. Why is this?

I think this question is straightforward but it has been awhile since I studied symmetric polynomials, Galois theory, etc. Any help is appreciated, as well as references. Thank you!

Comment: $$\Pi_{1\le \lambda < \mu \le d} (X - y_\lambda - y_\mu -h y_\lambda y_\mu)$$
$$\text{versus}$$
$$\prod_{1\le \lambda < \mu \le d} (X - y_\lambda - y_\mu -h y_\lambda y_\mu)$$
The first form above appeared, and I changed it to the second form, which is standard usage.  That's the difference between \Pi, which only yields the capital Greek letter, and \prod, which carries with it the appropriate formatting conventions. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be the field $F(y_1, \ldots , y_d)$.  Since $K$ is the adjunction to $F$ of all the roots of a polynomial in $F[X]$, $K$ is a splitting field over $F$.  Since we are in characteristic $0$, this means that $K$ is Galois over $F$.  In other words, if $x \in K$, and $\sigma x = x$ for every $F$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$, then in fact $x \in F$.

If $\sigma$ is any $F$-automorphism of $K$, then $\sigma$ permutes the elements $y_1, \ldots , y_d$ among themselves.  The coefficients of $g_h$ are symmetric functions of the elements $y_\lambda + y_\mu + h y_\lambda y_\mu$, so the coefficients of $g_h$ are fixed by $\sigma$.  So these coefficients must be in $F$, i.e. $g_h \in F[X]$.  For example, the constant term of $g_h$ is $$c_0 = \pm \prod\limits_{\lambda, \mu} (y_{\lambda} + y_\mu + h y_\lambda y_{\mu})$$ and you can see that $\sigma c_0 = c_0$ for every $\sigma \in \textrm{Gal}(K/F)$.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for